# ng-show/hide - based on a substring in a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm familiar with using **ng-show** and **ng-hide** when my bound data contains a specific word or piece of text. For example:

```
<div ng-show="myArray.Length > 20">
    Show something
</div>

<div ng-show="myData.Name == 'Harry Roberts'">
    Show something
</div>
```

However, how can i use `ng-show` to show when the bound data contains a certain value, for example, 'Current'. For example, if my JSON data:

```
{
    "MyAddresses": [
        {
            "Entry"  : "1",
            "Period" : "2011 - current",

        }, {
            "Entry"  : "2",
            "Period" : "2003 - 2011",

        }, {
            "Entry"  : "3",
            "Period" : "1998 - 2001",

        }
    ]
}


<div ng-show="myData.MyAddresses.Period ~ 'Current'">
    Show something
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the function `indexOf` to search for a substring in a string. It will return the position of the search string if found or will return -1.

So you can use an expression like `myData.MyAddresses.Period.indexOf('Current') != -1` to show/hide data

Answer (score 3):

Below code works for me to check the substring

​`<div ng-show = "address.indexOf('expected string')!=-1">
Show something​
</div>`